# Swift Local Notifications: Type Of Expression is Ambiguous Without More Context

Tags: swift, xcode8, ios10, uilocalnotification

I'm attempting to implement local notifications and am getting the error "Type of Expression is Ambiguous without More Context".

I've looked other related topics and many of them were either using an earlier version of Xcode (I'm using 8.o, ios 10) or provided the same piece of code I'm having issues with as a result. I apologize if I missed a post with the answer. I've copied and pasted this code from a [tutorial site](http://www.balancedcode.com/blog/files/swiftLocalNotifications.html), which seems to be the same code used on many other sites (and provided as an answer to other issues).

This code is meant to ask for permission for local notifications from the user

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UNNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert , .Badge , .Sound], categories: nil)) // This line sends back the error

    return true
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just "UN" instead of "UNNotificationSettings"? It was originally UIUserNotificationSettings (Or something along those lines) and I was prompter to change it to UNNotificationSettings, which seems to be working alright

Answer (score 0):

As per Swift 3 & iOS 10, do the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: nil)

    return true

}
```